# Load ajax after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is the first time that I'm using ajax with jquery and I'm new on jquery I have a structure

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  data_url = $('.lazy_content').attr("data-url");
    data_id = $('.lazy_content').attr("data-target-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: data_url,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loaderDiv").show();
            $("#" + data_id).html("");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).each(function(index, el) {
                $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                $("#" + data_id).html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="lazy_content" data-url="/ajax/yorumlar/@Model.OtelBilgileri.seflink" data-target-id="ajax-content-1">
  <h4 class="tur-main-baslik">COMMENTS</h4>
  <div id="ajax-content-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="/ajax/trustyou/@Model.OtelBilgileri.seflink" data-target-id="ajax-content-2">
  <h4 class="tur-main-baslik section-head">POSTS</h4>
  <div id="ajax-content-2"></div>
</div>
```

as you see I have `data-url` this data url has my ajax-file and I'm getting my ajax file but after page loading nothing work..whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Any error in your browser console? did you added jquery library before your code?

Comment: no but I guess problem is with my events

Comment: The problem is with your events, a div does not have an onload event, you could use document ready or window scroll events for example.

Comment: @andrew is there any example how to use ? I'm a new on jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

and I think you need to change your code like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    data_url = $('.lazy_content').attr("data-url");
    data_id = $('.lazy_content').attr("data-target-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: data_url,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loaderDiv").show();
            $("#" + data_id).html("");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).each(function(index, el) {
                $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                $("#" + data_id).html(data);
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Or iterate with each class i.e `.lazy_content`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.lazy_content').each(function(){
        data_url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        data_id = $(this).attr("data-target-id");

        $.ajax({
            url: data_url,
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(".loaderDiv").show();
                $("#" + data_id).html("");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).each(function(index, el) {
                    $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#" + data_id).html(data);
                });
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I have a lot of div to get my ajax file but this code only work for one div

Comment: All Right ! Could you please show some more code with jsfiddle ?

Comment: Ok.Updated my code and ajax works for only first div my ajax file is loaded for first div and another div doesn't load I guess it's about with `this` or something like that

Comment: Please check my new updated code... And let me know if its work or not?

Comment: and thank you so much I guess it's work but now second div laded but first div is not loading and give me a this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://localhost:83/ajax/trustyou/aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort`

Comment: As you mentioned its showing 500 internal server error. Please make sure your URL is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the javascript is in the HTML the DOM may not have loaded at the point you run the script.

encapsulating your javascript within the jquery 'on DOM loaded' function ( $(document).ready( function() { ) will fix that problem, code as follows.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.lazy_content').on("load", function() {
    data_url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    data_id = $(this).attr("data-target-id");

    $.ajax({
      url: data_url,
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(".loaderDiv").show();
        $("#" + data_id).html("");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(index, el) {
          $(".loaderDiv").hide();
          $("#" + data_id).html(data);
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm using with document.ready already I guess problem is with my event

Answer (score 0):

Load evnet is Only usable in window,img element.

If You use Jquery load function, You can use callback function.

```
$("#target").load("append.html",function(){
     // callback
});
```

another way, you append scripts below target html.